# How to create a command "home" or "quit" that returns to the main function of a program in python

Tags: python, user-interface

I have a program that displays a "main menu" with several options for users and then starts a method when an option is selected.  E.g. If you select "Add Name" the add_name method is executed and then the main menu is displayed again.

Inside each of the methods you can access from the menu are several prompts.  E.g. Inside of "Add Name" is the prompt "Add which name?".

I would like the user to be able to type "help" or "quit" from any prompt anywhere in the program and have the program display a help menu in the first case or return to the main menu in the second.

Is this possible?  How would a program like that be structured?

Comment: you would be best using pygame and checking for key press events

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a structured menu drawing system for console mode, like [curses](http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/charming_python_6.html) or [urwid](http://urwid.org/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to create a definition that specifically looks for these inputs any time a user inputs values and have it execute before any other definition.

Comment: Can you show me a basic implementation of what that would look like?
I was thinking of something fairly simple like this but I don't know how to make a method call a return on -its- calling method.